# Stay filtered if already filtered in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

If anyone can think of a better title for this, please don't hesitate to change it.

I am quite new to jQuery and have ran into an issue with filtering elements.

I am filtering DIVS with the `data-` attribute via a `checkbox` using the change function.

My issue is that if I filter on one `data` attribute (`colour`) and I then filter on another attribute (`brand`) the elements are all hidden. But if I untick one of the filters, the elements pop back up even though they are still filtered by another attribute.

Is there anyway I can stop this from happening?

Here is the code .

```
<div data-brand="Nike" data-price="31" data-colour="Blue">Blue</div>
<div data-brand="Nike" data-price="31" data-colour="Red"> Red </div>
Colours:
Blue<input type="checkbox" id="BlueCB" checked>
Red<input type="checkbox" id="RedCB" checked>

Brand: Nike <input type="checkbox" id="NikeCB" checked>

<script>
    var BlueSelector = $('#BlueCB');

    BlueSelector.on("change", function(){
        if($(this).is(":checked"))
        {
            var divs = $("div[data-colour=Blue]");  
            divs.css("display",  "block");
        } else 
        {
            var divs = $("div[data-colour=Blue]");  
            divs.css("display",  "none");
        }
    });

    var RedSelector = $('#RedCB');

    RedSelector.on("change", function(){
        if($(this).is(":checked"))
        {
            var divs = $("div[data-colour=Red]");  
            divs.css("display",  "block");
        } else 
        {
            var divs = $("div[data-colour=Red]");  
            divs.css("display",  "none");
        }
    });

    var NikeSelector = $('#NikeCB');

    NikeSelector.on("change", function(){
        if($(this).is(":checked"))
        {
            var divs = $("div[data-colour=Nike]");  
            divs.css("display",  "block");
        } else 
        {
            var divs = $("div[data-brand=Nike]");  
            divs.css("display",  "none");
        }
    });
</script>
```

To replicate problem, untick the nike checkbox, then untick the blue checkbox and tick again. The element will pop back out, which is the issue.

Here is the [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/z9qbecLx/1/)

This probably doesn't sound like the best explanation, but I have as best as I could.. you will understand after you play with the fiddle.

Comment: So you only want the color check boxes to work if the NikeSelector is checked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very late addition, but had a momentarily forgotten fiddle open in the background. After a letter of the Forgotten Fiddle action group, I decided to post it after all.

Since the goal seems to be to hide data related to unchecked boxes, rather than show any data for which any data-attribute is checked, you could create a blacklist for which data elements should be hidden. 
As well as mentioned in other answers my preference would be to put all meta data in (data)-tags, such as `<input type="checkbox" data-type="colour" data-value="Blue" checked>`, but rather than keep separate filters, create a combined filter of the elements that should be hidden. Since jquery can easily select on element attributes, the jquery functionality can be used to do the filtering for you.

The idea is that by determining the filters like this, any new data attribute can be added (such as size, which I took the liberty of adding in the fiddle too).

```
var $boxes = $('input[data-type]'), //all input boxes with data-type attribute
    $dataObjects =$(); //will be filled with all bound data elements
$boxes.each(function(ind, inp){     //create filter information
    var type = inp.dataset.type, value = inp.dataset.value; //for older browsers, use  $(inp).data('type')  
  var filter =  'div[data-' + type +'="' + value +'"]';     
  inp.dataset.filter = filter;
    $.merge($dataObjects,$(filter));
}); 

$boxes.change(function(){
    var blacklist = $boxes.filter(function(i,b){return !b.checked})
    .map(function(i,b){return b.dataset.filter}).toArray().join();
  $dataObjects.hide().not(blacklist).show();
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z9qbecLx/6/)

Comment: Wow.. this is pretty awesome too!! Works perfectly

Comment: How could I reverse this so that all elements show even though at first all checkboxes are unchecked. and as you start ticking, only show elements that are ticked? - I tried to edit it myself but it became an issue when I only had 'Blue' selected and nothing else showed because 'Nike' and 'Medium' wasn't also selected.

Comment: Depends if multiple checkboxes checked should behave as `and` or `or`. For the `or` approach, you could reverse the selection by selecting the checked boxes and use `filter` instead of `not` to show all items that qualify for any of the filters: https://jsfiddle.net/z9qbecLx/7/  (the || in `show || '*'`  resets the filter to show everything when no boxes are checked). For `And`, the same approach can be used, but the jquery selector should be joined without a ',' : https://jsfiddle.net/z9qbecLx/8/

Answer (score 3):

The below code will work for multi brands as well as multi colours, which is done by having a separated filters array for brands and colours, if the filter is checked we add to the corresponding filters array, then finally we check the each `div` and check whether it has both the brand and colour keywords, if both met we show<sup>( * )</sup> it, otherwise we hide<sup>( * )</sup> it:

[**JS Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/097552pu/)

```js
var Divs = $('.divs'),
  CheckBoxes = $('.chbx'),
  BlueSelector = $('#BlueCB'),
  RedSelector = $('#RedCB'),
  NikeSelector = $('#NikeCB'),
  Index, Colour, Brand;


CheckBoxes.on("change", function() {
  // Reset filters Arrays
  var ColoursFilters = [],
    BrandsFilters = [];

  // If Blue checkbox is checked, add it to colours array -
  // Otherwise it's unchecked, remove it from the colours array
  if (BlueSelector.is(":checked")) {
    ColoursFilters.push('Blue');
  } else if (BlueSelector.is(":checked") == false) {
    Index = ColoursFilters.indexOf('Blue');
    ColoursFilters.splice(Index, 'Blue');
  }

  // If Red checkbox is checked, add it to colours array -
  // Otherwise it's unchecked, remove it from the colours array
  if (RedSelector.is(":checked")) {
    ColoursFilters.push('Red');
  } else if (RedSelector.is(":checked") == false) {
    Index = ColoursFilters.indexOf('Red');
    ColoursFilters.splice(Index, 'Red');
  }

  // If Nike checkbox is checked, add it to brands array -
  // Otherwise it's unchecked, remove it from the brands array
  if (NikeSelector.is(":checked")) {
    BrandsFilters.push('Nike');
  } else if (NikeSelector.is(":checked") == false) {
    Index = BrandsFilters.indexOf('Red');
    BrandsFilters.splice(Index, 'Blue');
  }

  // Now we check for every colour and every brand -
  // If both conditions met, show the div, else hide it.
  Divs.each(function() {
    Colour = $(this).attr('data-colour');
    Brand = $(this).attr('data-brand');
    if ($.inArray(Colour, ColoursFilters) > -1) {
      if ($.inArray(Brand, BrandsFilters) > -1) {
        $(this).show();
      } else {
        $(this).hide();
      }
    } else {
      $(this).hide();
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="divs" data-brand="Nike" data-price="31" data-colour="Blue">
  Blue</div>
<div class="divs" data-brand="Nike" data-price="31" data-colour="Red">
  Red</div>
Colours: Blue
<input class="chbx" type="checkbox" id="BlueCB" checked>Red
<input class="chbx" type="checkbox" id="RedCB" checked>
<br>Brand: Nike
<input class="chbx" type="checkbox" id="NikeCB" checked>
```

---

**EDIT 1:**

In case you want to set all checkboxes default state to be unchecked, we create a function `checkFilters()` having all the logic in and we call it as the page first loads as well as every time one of the checkboxes state is changed, as shown in this [**JS Fiddle 2**](https://jsfiddle.net/hhbyum59/1/).

---

**EDIT 2:**

The javascript code still having redundant code and this is only for 3 checkboxes, supposing there are 10 brands and you have 5 colours for each brand then the code would look messy and repeated with more chances for bugs, to make the code more robust, flexible and also much shorter, we add a `data-type` and `data-keyword` attributes to every checkbox, and depending on the value of the `data-type` attribute we return the respective array and push the value of the `data-keyword` attribute into the corresponding array so it will work no matter how many colours or brands checkboxes there are, just like in this [**JS Fiddle 3**](https://jsfiddle.net/90n4xhmr/)

*Input example*:

```
<input class="chbx" type="checkbox" id="BlueCB" data-type="Colours" data-keyword="Blue" checked> Red
```

*JS:*

```
function checkFilters() {
    // Reset filters Arrays
    var ColoursFilters = [],
    BrandsFilters = [];

   CheckBoxes.each(function() {
       var $th = $(this), ArrayType, keyword;

       // Using ternary operator, we return the array that corresponds to the data-type
       ArrayType = $th.attr('data-type') == 'Colours' ? ColoursFilters : BrandsFilters;
       keyword = $th.attr('data-keyword');
       if ($th.is(':checked')) {
           ArrayType.push(keyword);
       } else if ($th.is(":checked") == false) {
           Index = ArrayType.indexOf(keyword);
           ArrayType.splice(Index, keyword);
       }
   });
   // ...  
}
```

---

<sup>*</sup> Note that jQuery [`.show()`](https://api.jquery.com/show()/) "*is roughly equivalent to calling `.css( "display", "block")`*" while [`.hide()`](https://api.jquery.com/hide()/) "*is roughly equivalent to calling `.css( "display", "none")`*"

Comment: Thankyou for an absolutely brilliant answer. JSFiddle 3 was EXACTLY what I wanted. - I have just had a go with your code, although I don't understand it 100% I have edited it. I added another Type ('Size'). Would you have a quick look to see if I have done it right? https://jsfiddle.net/60L6pzs8/3/  - Thanks again.

Comment: @Dan that was nicely done, all you needed is to add a "small" `input` to the HTML, and also you don't need the line with the ternary operator since you have done it with the 3-stages `if-else` statements, check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/zhmopvgd/1/ which has the ternary operator line commented and the "small" size filter added to the HTML

Comment: Also I think you understood the code very well except for the "ternary operator", basically this is a simplified version of a *2-stages* `if-else` statement, this `Z = (conditionX > Y) ? A : B` is equivalent to `if(conditionX > Y) { Z = A; }else{ Z = B; }` , for more information about the ternary operator check this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jQuery to add a `data-selected` attribute to checked items. I'm assuming the items are not selected by default. By using the `attr` property on the selected divs, you can add such an attribute. To make sure only filtered selectors appear when you click on the Nike checkbox, you want to add a data attribute to the selector for that check event, turning it into `$("div[data-brand=Nike][data-select=true]")`. Also, for brevity, you can chain the `attr` property and the `css` property together.

https://jsfiddle.net/tfr9zh0w/

```js
var BlueSelector = $('#BlueCB');

BlueSelector.on("change", function(){
if($(this).is(":checked"))
{
var divs = $("div[data-colour=Blue]");  
divs.attr('data-select', true).css("display",  "block");
} else 
{
var divs = $("div[data-colour=Blue]");  
divs.removeAttr('data-select').css("display",  "none");
}
});

var RedSelector = $('#RedCB');

RedSelector.on("change", function(){
if($(this).is(":checked"))
{
var divs = $("div[data-colour=Red]");  
divs.attr('data-select', true).css("display",  "block");
} else 
{
var divs = $("div[data-colour=Red]");  
divs.removeAttr('data-select').css("display",  "none");
}
});

var NikeSelector = $('#NikeCB');

NikeSelector.on("change", function(){
if($(this).is(":checked"))
{
var divs = $("div[data-brand=Nike][data-select=true]");  
divs.css("display",  "block");
} else 
{
var divs = $("div[data-brand=Nike]");  
divs.css("display",  "none");
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-brand="Nike" data-price="31" data-colour="Blue">
Blue </div>
<div data-brand="Nike" data-price="31" data-colour="Red">
Red </div>
Colours:
Blue<input type="checkbox" id="BlueCB" checked>
Red<input type="checkbox" id="RedCB" checked>

Brand: Nike <input type="checkbox" id="NikeCB" checked>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add to your if statements for the color selectors to determine if the Nike box is checked.

If the Nike box isn't checked, I personally would uncheck and disable the color check boxes.

https://jsfiddle.net/z9qbecLx/4/

```
var BlueSelector = $('#BlueCB');
var RedSelector = $('#RedCB');
var NikeSelector = $('#NikeCB');

BlueSelector.on("change", function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked") && NikeSelector.is(":checked"))
    {
        var divs = $("div[data-colour=Blue]");  
        divs.css("display",  "block");
    }
    else 
    {
        var divs = $("div[data-colour=Blue]");  
        divs.css("display",  "none");
    }
});

RedSelector.on("change", function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked") && NikeSelector.is(":checked"))
    {
        var divs = $("div[data-colour=Red]");  
        divs.css("display",  "block");
    }
    else 
    {
        var divs = $("div[data-colour=Red]");  
        divs.css("display",  "none");
    }
});

NikeSelector.on("change", function(){
  if($(this).is(":checked"))
  {
    RedSelector.prop('disabled', false);
    BlueSelector.prop('disabled', false);
    var divs = $("div[data-colour=Nike]");  
    divs.css("display",  "block");
  }
  else 
  {
    RedSelector.prop('checked', false).prop('disabled', true);
    BlueSelector.prop('checked', false).prop('disabled', true);
    var divs = $("div[data-brand=Nike]");  
    divs.css("display",  "none");
  }
});
```